# How do I link external Javascript file to a html document in Play Framework project?

Tags: javascript, html, scala, playframework

This is my scala.html file code.

```
@()
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Spin To Win </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("stylesheets/styles.css")">
        <script  type="text/javascript" src='@routes.Assets.versioned("scripts/test.js")'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> This is title </h1>
        <input type="button" value="click" onclick="showAlert()">
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my javascript file.

```
function showAlert() {
    alert("Hello");
}
```

This is the file directory where the javascript is stored.
[image]

**Output**

CSS works correctly.

But Javsascript doesn't work. Nothing happens when I click  the button.

**Update**

So if I just put a alert in the test.js outside of any function, it works. The alert is displayed when the page loads.

```
alert("hello");
```

So, this means the js file is linked properly. 
But if I put the code in a function like earlier and link it to a button it doesn't work.

Comment: check for console errors,

Comment: Did you ever find the answer here?  I have the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't actually executing your function.
Your code should be:

```
function showAlert() {
    alert("Hello");
}
showAlert();
```

For buttons, it should be:

```
<button onclick="showAlert()">Button</button>
```

Comment: I have this in my code. <input type="button" value="click" onclick="showAlert()">